# Can't See Windows Phone Template in Visual Studio 2012 for windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

Previously I used Visual Studio 2012 for Windows Phone 8. and developed some projects.

But, suddenly there is no options for creating windows phone App.

If i try to create a new project will show error popup like this.

[image]

Comment: Clearly something messed-up your installation like changed or deleted some path. the easy way to solve it is just reinstall or run repair of VS.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the Visual Studio Command Prompt shortcut and then  select Run as Administrator

Run below command

```
devenv /installvstemplates
devenv /resetsettings
```

http://www.tanchunsiong.com/visual-studio-2012-no-template-information-found/

UPDATE:

> **This switch is supported only for Visual Studio partner development, and is not available in Express editions.** You must run devenv as an
>   administrator in order to use the /Setup (devenv.exe) and
>   /InstallVSTemplates (devenv.exe) switches. For more information, see
>   User Permissions and Visual Studio.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms241279.aspx

Comment: I tried this way. But it shows an error like this
'devenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command. Operable program or batch file

Comment: Yes. Visual Studio 2012 for Windows phone is available only for Express edition. But i use my developer license to get the key for using this product/

Answer (score 0):

This may not work on the express version. If you have a Professional or Ultimate version of VS, try running the installer again. Then choose "Modify" option, and select "Windows Phone 8.0 SDK" from the list.

For more information see [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/04b0878c-9468-4b65-864b-caef562735fe/visual-studio-2013-ultimate-no-template-for-windows-phone-8-app-development?forum=visualstudiogeneral)