# No windows phone project template found

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

Ive got visual studio 2013 Ultimate RC 2 installed with windows phone 8.0 SDK.

There is no widnows phone project template. How can I get it ?

thank You very much for any help

I try to finish this tutorial but its impossible :( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402571(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_Creatinganewprojectfromatemplate

I think that it can be the issue http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj735581(v=vs.105).aspx

thats why im looking for the way to run windows phone template and not windows store widnows phone template

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026463/cant-see-windows-phone-template-in-visual-studio-2012-for-windows-phone-8) might help you, by the way did you select the optional feature `Windows Phone 8.0 SDK` when installing?

Comment: Yes i selected this feature

Comment: You find Windows Phone Templates under Windows Store-> Windows Phone

Comment: but then in toolbox there are only Common XAML controls and no Windows Phone Controlls :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have the Toolbox like this when you are in a Page you should repair your VS 2013

[image]

Comment: When I create web app it looks like this but when I create windows phone app from web store template it doesnt

Comment: Repair your visual studio

Comment: run appwiz.cpl double click Visual Studio 2013 and then Repair/Reinstall

Comment: Before doing that try to do right click Reset on the toolbox

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj735581(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: right click on your toolbox->`ChoosItems`->`Windows Phone Silverlight Components`  then choose `WebBrowser`

Comment: you said that i should repair vs. now You say that I have to use windows phone silverlight components. Weird...

Comment: i thought you don't want to manually add the tools in the toolbox and repairing was (easier)

Comment: it's is remairing right now, 22 minutes and still going... visual studio is piece of crap

Comment: right click on your toolbox->ChoosItems->Windows Phone Silverlight Components then choose WebBrowser -> didnt help as well

Comment: you don't have WebBrowser in that list or what?

Comment: do you have teamviewer? cause it's getting too long here

Comment: tw: 210 387 984 p: 4202

Comment: I think that you should remove visual studio 2013 and wp8 sdk and then when you install the vs 2013 choose everything and after that apply the update too

Comment: vs 2013RC2 screws things up. I uninstalled vs 2013. Then installed it with widnows phone 9.0 sdk option checked. Everything was ok. Then I installed vs 2013 RC2 update and situation is as previously

Comment: It should appear in appwiz.cpl

Answer (score 0):

You can see here where you can find Windows Phone Project Templates under VS 2013 RC

[image]

Comment: but then in toolbox there are only Common XAML controls and no Windows Phone Controlls :(

Comment: for example it is impossible then to add web browser to the widnows app

Comment: That is another problem, it's not about the template :D

Comment: I try to finish this tutorial but its impossible :( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402571(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_Creatinganewprojectfromatemplate

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your project templates exanding the store apps category and selecting the Windows Phone apps?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj735581(v=vs.105).aspxjust check this out and the webbrowser control in the grid:

Answer (score 0):

You are probably creating a Windows Phone 8.1 Project which is different from Windows Phone 8.0. That's the reason. Check if you can see Windows Phone 8.0 emulators from target list.